# nginx reverse proxy to localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have application running on my AWS EC2 Instance's localhost:8080.

In order to use these Web portal, I have install nginx on EC2 and reversed proxy localhost so that I can access Web UI on my browser.

**Nginx.conf file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

   location /$request_uri {
   proxy_pass http://localhost$request_uri;

} 

}
```

When hitting EC2 URL on my browser,I successfully seeing homepage of application.

But when I hit any url let's say /admin, Nginx redirects to my local computer's **localhost:8080/admin** not Server's localhost. 
All i want is that when hit any url nginx should forward the request to localhost:8080{$URL} and return me the browser.

please suggest where I'm wrong. 
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You are missing the forward slashes for localhost in the second rule. So "http: //localhost", not http:localhost.

Comment: I did but getting same issue

Comment: Use the location /admin and you may have to put it above the location / rule. I think your first rule is the wildcard you are after. It proxy passes everything to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the second location.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

this should be enough to access anything you need.